# How can I check if an element contains any text?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm currently building a web scraper and I'm trying to find out how to tell if an element contains any text, to run code accordingly

like so:

```
if (element.hasText):
    doStuff()
```

I want to check this because the scraper sometimes says: *AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'*

Comment: you know `try/except`? and `text=True`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
try:
    if (element.hasText):
        doStuff()
except ValueError:
    #Contains no text
    continue
```

This basically tests the elements to see if it contains text, if it gives an error it skips it and you know it contains no text.